# How to make this a slow jQuery counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I am currently busy with making a new website.
I would like to make a counter on my website that shows visitors how many websites I made.
I am currently using Javascript and jQuery to do this. The only problem is that while using the for loop, the result shows very fast and I would like it to count up slowly. This is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var websites = 10;
    for (var i=0;i<websites;i++)
    {
        $('.webcounter').html(i);
    }
});
```

Any one has an idea to making the counter go slow?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This timer works in seconds, you can put the code to run after it's complete in the else section:

**Javascript**

```
function countdown(count){

    $('.webcounter').html(count);

    count -= 1;

    if(count >= 0)
        setTimeout("countdown("+count+")", 1000);
    else
        alert("Countdown Complete");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    countdown(10);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="webcounter">Webcounter Holder</div>​
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/silver89/SBXAQ/8/

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var interval = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick guess, but try something like this (i'm at work and cant test myself, heheh)

```
var websites = 10, tmrSiteCount;

function siteCount(i) {
    if (i <= websites) {
        $('.webcounter').html(i);
        tmrSiteCount = setTimeout(function() { siteCount(i++); }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(tmrSiteCount);
    };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    tmrSiteCount = setTimeout(function() { siteCount(1); });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval):

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GKucL/1/)**

**HTML**

```
​<div class="websites">0</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var websites = 10;
    var counter = 1;
    var id = setInterval(function(){ 
        $('.websites').text(counter);
        counter++;
        if(counter > websites){ clearInterval(id);}
    }, 500);    
});​
```